# Tried writing bin sort using vectors in c++. Didnt get the desired output

Tags: c++, c++17, nodes, codeblocks

This is code for bin sort using vectors in c++. I used code blocks IDE. when i execute the program the program asks me to enter the values. once i enter all the values it shuts down claiming segmentation fault. I guess the problem somewhere lies in the `binsort` function itself

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
}*first;
void binSort(vector <int> &v, int n)
{
   int s=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       if(s<v[i])
       {
           s=v[i];
       }
   }
   s=s+1;
   Node *arr[s];
   int j;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       j=v[i];
       first=arr[j];
       if(arr[j]==nullptr)
       {
           arr[j]=new Node;
           arr[j]->data=v[i];
           arr[j]->next=nullptr;
       }
       else
       {
           while(first!=nullptr)
           {
               if(first->next==nullptr)
               {
                   Node *t=new Node;
                   t->data=v[i];
                   t->next=nullptr;
                   first->next=t;
                   break;
               }
               else
               {
                   first=first->next;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   int m=0;
   for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
   {
       if(arr[i]!=nullptr)
       {
           first=arr[i];
           while(first!=nullptr)
           {
               v[m]=first->data;
               m++;
               Node *t=first;
               first=first->next;
               delete t;
           }
       }
   }
}
int main()
{
    vector <int> v;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the no. of elements you want to sort\n";
    cin>>n;
    int d;
    cout<<"Enter the values\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>d;
        v.push_back(d);
    }
    binSort(v, n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't guess where the segfault is. Use the debugger built into Code::blocks to know for sure where it is. Learning to use the debugger may be the only thing standing between you and having more time for other studies (or the occasional night off).

Comment: `Node *arr[s];` is a Variable Length Array. They are not legal in Standard C++ for quite a few reasons, but most important here is it's one-stop shopping for all your mystery bug needs. Strongly consider replacing this with another `std::vector`.

Comment: @user4581301, yeah there is no segfault in his code. I debugged it. It is literally at `Node *arr[s];` like you mentioned.

Comment: Your answer is wrong it does not solve the problem.

Comment: `vector<Node*> arr(s, NULL);`

Comment: @SaiSreenivas, nice. I upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you never initialised the array `arr`.

And as it was mentioned in the comment section, variable-length arrays are not part of standard c++ so better to replace that allocating dynamically or you can use `vector`

You need to initialise the vector `arr` to `nullptr`.

```cpp
vector<Node*> arr(s, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
}*first;
void binSort(vector <int> &v, int n)
{
   int s=0;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       if(s<v[i])
       {
           s=v[i];
       }
   }
   s=s+1;
   Node *arr[s];
   for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
   {
       arr[i]=nullptr;
   }
   int j;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
       j=v[i];
       first=arr[j];
       if(arr[j]==nullptr)
       {
           arr[j]=new Node;
           arr[j]->data=v[i];
           arr[j]->next=nullptr;
       }
       else
       {
           while(first!=nullptr)
           {
               if(first->next==nullptr)
               {
                   Node *t=new Node;
                   t->data=v[i];
                   t->next=nullptr;
                   first->next=t;
                   break;
               }
               else
               {
                   first=first->next;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   int m=0;
   for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
   {
       if(arr[i]!=nullptr)
       {
           first=arr[i];
           while(first!=nullptr)
           {
               v[m]=first->data;
               m++;
               Node *t=first;
               first=first->next;
               delete t;
           }
       }
   }
}
int main()
{
    vector <int> v;
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the no. of elements you want to sort\n";
    cin>>n;
    int d;
    cout<<"Enter the values\n";
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>d;
        v.push_back(d);
    }
    binSort(v, n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<v[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

I found the answer for this myself. there was a for loop missing in the previous code to initialize the array as null.

Comment: @GenoC no it ran smoothly after this addition